Are Syed and Baby_philosopher the same user?
The insight struck me after encountering a recent question by Syed (which appears to have been deleted by the user, though it’s likely the moderators can still view it). In this question, Syed attempted to defend Dawkins' philosophical status, expressing a sentiment similar to that found in this question: Why is Dawkins not respected amongst philosophers?, asked by Baby_philosopher. This raised my suspicions. I began examining their profiles and noticed that both users share common interests, as evidenced by the tags and questions they’ve posted. Both also exhibit a peculiar pattern of asking many questions in quick succession (e.g., 6–8 questions in under 24 hours).
Additionally, Baby_philosopher is currently temporarily suspended for ban evasion. This implies there was an earlier banned account, followed by a new account that was created, detected, and subsequently banned again for evasion. If this theory holds, the current account would represent a second (or third, or fourth, I don't know) attempt at ban evasion.
Are my detective skills accurate, or am I overthinking this and these are genuinely different users?

UPDATE
Another point worth noting: Syed is a Muslim name (source), and Baby_philosopher disclosed at least twice that they are a former Muslim:

I deal with something very, very similar, where I fear the existence of hell given the religion that I grew up in. I grew up Muslim and came across seeming coincidences that seem extremely hard to explain without a God.


I grew up Muslim and remember reading a lot about these patterns. They confused me just as well. First of all, because Islam has so many rituals that involve numbers such as saying certain things 3 times or 33 times every day, I suspect it sort of puts you in an OCD like state where you start seeing patterns everywhere. This is primarily the reason why you’ll often find Muslims focus on these kinds of things much more than other religious people nowadays.


UPDATE 2:
Additional accounts with very similar questions:

Kelly (also banned for ban evasion)
user62907 (aka thinkingman), currently deleted.


UPDATE 3 - Similar content and speech patterns:
Example #1 - Citing Elliott Sober's papers
Syed's answer:

In science, this alternative hypothesis is prima facie plausible enough (for the most part) such that we don’t need to implement the further step I just mentioned. If it seemed too implausible, we would likely not be testing it in the first place. As such, it is purely a matter of convenience that significance testing is “good enough” for our purposes even if it is based on a fallacy.
See Sober’s paper here that goes into more detail on this: https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/kk3n/simplicity/sober1999.pdf

thinkingman's question:

A probabilistic version of Modus Tollens says "If P, then Q is very improbable. Q. Therefore, P is very improbable". Elliott Sober, in his paper against the design argument, describes this as a fallacy. See the paper here: http://philonantes.free.fr/ElliottSober_IntelligentDesignAndProbabilityReasoning.PDF. For example, there is a 1/52 chance to get a seven of hearts from a deck. Suppose you do get that card. This does not imply it is improbable that this occurred by chance.

Example #2 - David Deutsch, epistemology, Bayesian reasoning, and Quantum Mechanics
Syed's question:

In the article here, David Deutsch argues: By ‘Bayesian’ philosophy of science [...]

thinkingman's comment:

The question was about philosophy, not physics. Although here’s an interesting talk by David Deutsch who recommends expunging the notion from physics as a whole since in his view, probability just isn’t an actual process in reality: m.youtube.com/watch?v=wfzSE4Hoxbc –
user62907 Commented Aug 17, 2023 at 18:40

thinkingman's question:

As David Deutsch would put it, science has never been about increasing your credence in a certain belief or maximizing it for true beliefs. Instead, it has always been about good vs. bad explanations and maximizing explanatory power. Does a Bayesian system then give undue credit to theories with no explanatory power that it doesn’t deserve?

Baby_Philosopher's question: Is David Deutsch correct in stating that the Copenhagen interpretation of QM has few defenders left?
See also: How is this Linda example addressed by Bayesian thinking?, How do I validate my confidence in things?
Example #3 - Richard Dawkins and God

Syed's question: Does the fact that electrons share the same property need an explanation?


Richard Swinburne in his book Is There A God? argues that this does, and further argues that the fact that there are trillions of particles sharing the same property is the height of unexplained complexity.
As Richard Dawkins indicates in his book review, [...]
From what I gather, this highlights the difference between quantitative and qualitative parsimony. As per the SEP, it seems to indicate that the philosophical literature is more biased towards the kind of simplicity Dawkins talks about rather than Swinburne.


Baby_philosopher's question: Why is Dawkins not respected amongst philosophers?


After reading peoples’ opinions of Dawkins over the years where he is known to be arrogant and brash, I decided to actually delve into what he says and watch some of his videos and read some of his books.
From doing this, it seems that not only is he at the very least well versed in arguments pertaining to God, he is arguably even a good philosopher.


thinkingman's question: Dawkins on God: What are the strongest counters to his argument?


Regardless of what you think of Dawkins, his strongest argument against God is the argument from improbability. The argument can be summarized as such:

Example #4 - retort

Syed's latest question:


I presume that the retort to this would be that the concept of specified complexity wouldn’t apply to God since He consists of no parts or some other reason a theist can think of, but I’m not sure how this wouldn’t be committing the special pleading fallacy. If the theist does this, then I’m also not sure why a person can’t come up with reasons as to why a particular natural pattern doesn’t fit the concept of specified complexity.


thinkingman's question:


I can imagine a retort being that it is subjective but one can make models based on certain classes of past data and see which models predict the future better. But that doesn’t tell you what the “correct” probability is. It just tells you what model works the best. Where is the concept of probability actually needed here?

Example #5 - probability and plausibility
Syed's question:

But I’m having trouble understanding this reasoning since a) we don’t even know how life started and b) it is one thing for chemicals to react together to form basic life but a whole different thing to have the exact, right kind of evolutionary process that results in intelligent life forms like us. The latter seems incredibly more improbable, perhaps even unlikely enough for even the sheer size of the universe to not matter.
How do we evaluate the probability or plausibility of life forms similar to us existing or is this completely unknowable?

thinkingman's question 1 and question 2:

Let’s say that one argues that assignments of probabilities to different possible realities being true cannot reasonably be assigned. The rationale for this may be that probabilities seem meaningless or that even if they were meaningful, there is no justification to use the principle of indifference for them. The principle of indifference, as a reminder, states that probabilities among propositions with an absence of knowledge should be equiprobable.


When choosing between two theories, should you believe in the more plausible one? Or have a degree of belief in both?
Suppose you have two theories explaining data and no other theory is possible such that they are logically exhaustive. You know all there is to know about the data and theories.
Should you, now,
A) Believe in the one more plausible to you and call it a day in an “all out sense”
B) Have a degree of belief in both

Baby_philosopher's question:

Second, cannot a person raise the same contention against God? If God designed the constants for life, one can ask: why did God not design a universe using any of the other constants that aren’t designed for life? Of course, a natural answer to this question may be to say that God cares about us or that in His very nature is propelled to create constants that are suited for life. But then why can’t one just say that the universe is destined to have constants that lead to life by its very nature? This might seem unintuitive but I fail to see how this explanation is any worse than God. In fact, I think one can make a similar argument to address his rock example. Why couldn’t nature just happened to be set in a way such that it produced a formation saying “Hi Robin Collins.” given that this actually happened even if the probability of this happening is very low apriori. Why is this naturalistic explanation any less plausible than a God happening to exist that was ultimately also set to create that rock formation instead of all the other states of affairs reality could have been ordained as?

Kelly's question:

But there are certain cases in which hypotheses seem to be implausible even without a defined probability. For example, if someone says “well, actually, John didn’t kill michael despite finding his fingerprints on his body and finding evidence of his intention to murder. An invisible, undetectable goblin or being or god who was controlling John through unknowable means killed Michael.” many would find this extremely implausible. And yet, it would seem to make less sense to attach a probability to this. How often has an invisible goblin or being done things? What data can we look at to attach a figure to this kind of explanation at work, even approximately?
Does this mean plausibility is more fundamental than probability? How does one talk about the former without the latter in a still reasonable fashion?

Example #6 - atleast (without space between at and least)
Syed

Of course, there is currently no evidence (atleast evidence that everyone would agree on) that ... (question)


Either way, does this not give atleast some level of reasonable justification to believe in the continuance of a pattern without ... (question)


In libertarian free will, actions are chosen without determinism, or atleast not complete determinism... (question)


For example, I can atleast intuitively grasp the idea that even given bazillions of years, matter without guidance would not spontaneously form into an airplane...(question)


I can’t seem to find many responses to this in the philosophical literature despite it, atleast to me, seeming to be a better argument against fine tuning and other proposed design arguments than... (question)

Baby_philosopher

Similarly, atleast from an ontology perspective, the universe exists in both theism and naturalism. But God and the “supernatural” only exist in one of these perspectives. So unless you can successfully argue that God is necessary to explain the universe, then atleast from a simplicity standpoint, I don’t see how one can argue against Oppy’s point. (answer)


But now you have X and Y rather than just X which is arguably necessarily more complex (atleast from an ontological perspective). (question)


My curious nature seems to always want me to figure out the truth, atleast in a way where I am reasonably certain. (question)
(question)


Now, let’s assume that we don’t live in a determined world. Then, life came about atleast partially randomly. Then, either a) God created life (out of His free will which is supposedly random) or b) natural laws, in a somewhat random fashion (such as through quantum mechanics) resulted in life. (answer)


This then gives us atleast a weak inductive reason to prefer the designer explanation than the non designer one.” (question)

thinkingman

It is then unsurprising that atleast one of them would turn out to be meaningful. (question)


It is then unsurprising that atleast one of them would turn out to be meaningful. (question)


even if the chance of atleast ONE coin in the history of coins landing on heads 30 times may as well be close to one (and possibly higher than 0.9) (question)


In the case of the previous example, we have data that shows that professional dart players atleast exist. In this case, we have no prior evidence that suggests psychics exist. (question)


Now, a) of course has a very low probability. However, given that things in the universe are for the most part deterministic atleast on the macro scale, one could argue that if it occurred by chance, the “real probability” of him guessing 7 straight lotteries is the probability of whatever initial conditions.  (question)

Kelly

There seem to be many contexts in which it makes sense to define a probability or atleast an approximate one and attach that to a certain proposition. If that is very low, it is often taken to be implausible. (question)

More uses of the word "atleast" on the whole site can be found at: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22atleast%22
I consider the systematic use of "atleast" to be the most powerful signal. As of now, the link above yields 111 results, with the overwhelming majority of uses coming from thinkingman, Baby_philosopher, and Syed. Curiously, even Kelly used it once, despite being a throwaway account that got banned very quickly.

Having watched the baby-philosopher poster over several name changes to evade bans, I would rate this as likely.  However, as a non-mod, my main interest is in the value of a poster to the community, not their past offenses.  The earliest personas of this poster were hostile and contentious, which justifiably led to the initial ban.  He/she/they has gradually learned mutual respect, and argumentative self-discipline, and other than the irritatingly obsessive posting quantity, Syed is now a well-behaved contributor.

Aren't you the same person who used to post on the now-closed account that is currently user62907?

I've investigated and believe Syed and Baby_philosopher to be different users.

@JonathanZ I did some googling and it turns out that user62907 used to be called thinkingman. Interestingly, and to reinforce my suspicions, I remember Kristian Berry accusing Syed of being thinkingman evading his ban. This took place in the comments of one my earlier questions, but I don't remember which one. I know it's anecdotal evidence, but I see it as an important data point. You can ask Kristian directly if you don't believe me.

@causative See above.

@user80226 I have access to identifying information that suggests they are different users, in a way that couldn't easily be forged with a proxy. We can't be certain, but it is possible that two people just happen to have similar interests in philosophy.

If you want to tell someone about a user potentially breaking the rules, notify the moderators using a custom flag. It doesn't seem appropriate to discuss such things in public posts.

@NotThatGuy "It doesn't seem appropriate to discuss such things in public posts" - Why?

@user80226 It's not appropriate because it's only really something moderators can deal with. Moderators have far more information to be able to use for investigation (whereas regular users can mostly note similarities between someone's posts, which is a much less reliable signal, except for the most extreme cases). Regular users can't issue warnings or suspensions. They can just downvote / close vote / flag-bomb someone's posts, which is an inappropriate way to "punish" a user (especially if they're innocent), and it's not unlikely to happen in response to Meta posts (related: "meta effect").

"possibly two people just happen to have similar interests in philosophy" - what are the odds? Evidence of Intelligent Design? Hmm

@causative I added a new point worth considering to my question.

@causative you may want to have a look at the last update to my question

That's our job and we do have more means to collect evidence. Yet, it has to be conclusive. Presumptive evidence does not suffice. Please understand that I/we do check on a regular basis and act accordingly when there is enough evidence.

I’m voting to close this question because us moderators are aware of patterns and will deal with it when our guidelines are met.

@PhilipKlöcking I added a sixth example with a very peculiar "written idiosyncrasy"  that constitutes in my sincere opinion a very powerful signal bordering on a knockout argument. I don't know what creative ideas you would come up with to explain all the lines of evidence away. At some point the preponderance of evidence should make the abductive case undeniably clear beyond any reasonable doubt.

@PhilipKlöcking - Can you take the further step of deleting, or maybe freezing, it? It has become a platform where a single user can pursue their crusade against another user, and closing it doesn't seen to have stopped them. Thx

We do monitor these patterns (since shortly after account creation and first posts, actually) and while there are indications that suggest that, there is no conclusive evidence as of yet, which is the only reason why I have not acted already. Like I did in quite a few cases before.
That being said, please follow the suggestions by @NotThatGuy next time.

Philip, see the last point I added to my question.

Philip, just letting you know I updated the question once again (I was motivated by this)

By this same logic, user80226 and user 66156 (looks like his name is Mark) are the same user. Post histories include the same general theme of asking repetitive questions about intelligent design or reformed epistemology (the latter of which is a very specific topic). See examples here and here:
But you don’t see me making public posts about this in an effort to harm your reputation (I suppose these kinds of posts explain why I’m being downvoted sometimes for perfectly reasonable questions/answers).
As a side note, why is this kind of public barraging even allowed if the mods here make their own decisions in private? You don’t see me doing the same for the user who posted this question even though it is obvious that he is another deleted user himself. This also causes obvious revenge downvoting of posts

Funnily enough, JonathanZ accused me of being thinkingman (user62907), the same user Kristian Berry accused you of being some time ago :)

he was doing that because you kept modifying the tags of user62907’s posts over and over again to push it onto the front page. Either way, my point stands. I have zero doubt in my mind that you are the same user as user66156 (and who knows what the original name of that poster was since it now seems deleted). However, I don’t have an obsession with user histories like you and didn’t need to make a post about it like you. I only care about philosophy

@Syed They both never jumped accounts within the time span of 2 minutes though ;)
